# Magento 2 - For custom table collection object, getIdFieldName() is returning null

Tags: magento2, collection

Custom table created with name 'picklist_item' with 'item_id' column as primary key, in one of the admin controller action, collection object for 'picklist' table has been created and called getIdFieldName() but it is returning NULL, I am expecting it should return the primary key table column name.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the property `$_idFieldName` with the value of the table primary key in the collection class associated with your table:

`<Vendor>\<Module>\Model\ResourceModel\<ModelName>\Collection.php`:

`protected $_idFieldName = 'item_id';`

See original answer to a similar question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/145363/31483